# How to install Pandas using pip install on Mac

Tags: python, pandas, macos, installation, terminal

I have been reinstalling and installing Python multiple times on my computer, running into different issues each time. I have been doing this so that I can install the Pandas library.

Currently, if I run pip install pandas, I get this message:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

When I run `python --version` I get `-bash: python: command not found` but when I run `python3 --version` I get `Python 3.11.5`.

When I open my Library folder on my Mac, there is a Python folder in there and the only thing it has in there is a Python 2.7 folder. Not sure why that is either.

Comment: can you try `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: @ozgenbaris thank you so much that took me so long to fix ur a god. For any future installs will I have to write pip3 and if so, is there something I need to fix to change that? Or is that fine

Comment: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac

Comment: I think the problem is mac uses builtin pip which belongs to builtin python 2 when you run `pip`. So, you should not make changes on it. But as a suggestion: I'd use virtual environments for every project I work on. When you create and activate a virtual environment, then both `python` and `pip` commands are being aliased (or linked) to the binaries inside your virtual environment. So, you know which pip and which python you are using. So please take a look at virtual environments

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

1. `pip3 install pandas` as others pointed out, or you can do:
2. `python3 -m pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

You can install Pandas using pip3 (the package manager for Python 3):

pip3 install pandas

To verify that Pandas is installed correctly, run:

python3 -c "import pandas as pd; print(pd.**version**)"